# TypeScript type for object with one property type specified and all others being a different type

Tags: typescript

I need a general type for graph data that will always include `endDate: Date` and all other properties must be `number`. This doesn't work:

```
type GraphDatumEndDateType = { endDate: Date }
type GraphDatumType = Record<string, number> & GraphDatumEndDateType
```

It throws:

```
      Property 'endDate' is incompatible with index signature.
        Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

When a function is invoked with `GraphDataType` as the parameter:

```
export function getGraphData<T extends GraphDatumType>({
  data
}: {
  data: T[]
}): T[] {
  return data
}

const data = [
  {
    a: 0.8,
    b: 0.2,
    endDate: new Date
  }
]

const result = getGraphData({
  data // ts errors here
})
```

Comment: *What* throws that? It doesn't error in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgQzACwKIDsAmARBwIAq40AvFAN5QRa74BcUt0AvgFCiSyIq0CuAtkU5kAShADGAeziYAPAGdgcAJboA5gBoo6AQCMIcAHxQAZFyRoaeQsXbFzPPAiGkHyPoOIBtALqsgA).

Comment: @jonrsharpe [it throws on assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgQzACwKIDsAmARBwIAq40AvFAN5QRa74BcUt0AvgFCiSyIq0CuAtkU5kAShADGAeziYAPAGdgcAJboA5gBoo6AQCMIcAHxQAZFyRoaeQsVasA9PagBBeVARQAbghUJdAG2gAd2VgZHd0KGV+MH9lcVCoDghWKXRFKEldACsGeAs+QWIoMkoEBgBGACYAZi1qHGsGdAggxmsACgBKKDYgA). if you can change the data structure here, your life will be a lot easier if you change this to something like: `{ endDate: Date, data: Record<string, number> }`

Comment: @AlexWayne that makes sense, it wasn't the smartest move on my part. It's part of the examples in the [graphing library I'm using](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts#example-1).